# Why is this comparison between 2 arrays not working, if their contents differ from each other?

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've tried using `JSON.stringify()` to compare two arrays, I've tried comparing them without `JSON.stringify()`, but none of the way seems to capture the change in one of the array element. See it highlighted below:

Here's the piece of code I'm running:

```
    var duplicate = false;
    loop1:
    for (var x = 0; x < data.length; x++) {
      loop2:
      for (var j = 0; j < pushedDbData.length; j++) {
        if (JSON.stringify(data[x].join()) == JSON.stringify(pushedDbData[j].join())) {
          duplicate = true;
          break loop1;
        }
      }
    }
    if (duplicate == true) {
      Browser.msgBox('No change has been been made.');
      return;
```

[image]

Appreciate your help - as usual!

Comment: data is undefined. Please provide [mcve] that's minimal but also reproducible

Comment: You seem to be using this notation for some loops `loop1:` which is not valid javascript. I would expect an error but you seem to have it executing, so maybe you have not pasted the actual code you are using? Is that possible? Also you should add in some sample data so that the results can be tested and demonstrated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understood that from your script, the arrays of `data` and `pushedDbData` might be 2 dimensional array. In your script, when the arrays of `data` and `pushedDbData` are compared, one element of `data` is compared with all element of `pushedDbData`. At this time, when the element of `data` is the same with one of elements of `pushedDbData`, `duplicate` becomes `true`, even when all other elements are the same. I thought that this might be the reason of your issue.

In order to check the difference of the arrays, how about the following 2 patterns?

#### Pattern 1:

In this pattern, the arrays of `data` and `pushedDbData` are compared with the same index. In this case, each element of `data` and `pushedDbData` is compared with the same index. The sample script is as follows.

```
var res = data.filter((r, i) => pushedDbData[i] && JSON.stringify(r.join()) != JSON.stringify(pushedDbData[i].join()));
console.log(res)
```

- If each element of `data` and `pushedDbData` is different with the same index, the length of `res` is more than `1`.

#### Pattern 2:

In this pattern, the arrays of `data` and `pushedDbData` are compared with all elements. In this case, each element of `data` is compared with all elements of `pushedDbData`, and the same element and the different element are returned as the object.

```
var obj = data.reduce((o, r, i) => {
  pushedDbData.forEach((s, j) => o[JSON.stringify(s.join()) == JSON.stringify(r.join()) ? "sameElement" : "differentElement"].push({indexOfData: i, indexOfPushedDbData: j}));
  return o;   
}, {sameElement: [], differentElement: []});
console.log(obj)
```

- In this sample script, the output values are returned as the index of each array.

#### Note:

- From `but none of the way seems to capture the change in one of the array element.` in your question, I proposed above 2 patterns. When I misunderstood your goal, can I ask you about the sample output you expect? By this, I would like to modify it.

#### References:

- [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)
- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

### Added:

From your sample Spreadsheet and your current script, how about the following modification?

#### From

```
var duplicate = false;
loop1:
for (var x = 0; x < data.length; x++) {
  loop2:
  for (var j = 0; j < pushedDbData.length; j++) {
    console.log(data[x])
    if (data[x].join() == pushedDbData[j].join()) {
      duplicate = true;
      break loop1;
    }
  }
}
```

#### To:

```
var obj = data.reduce((o, r) => Object.assign(o, {[JSON.stringify(r.join())]: true}), {});
var duplicate = pushedDbData.every(e => obj[JSON.stringify(e.join())]);
```

- In this modified script, at first, an object is created from `data` for searching the values from `pushedDbData`. And, when the values of `data` are not included in `pushedDbData`, `true` is returned. Even when only one element is different, `false` is returned.

Comment: Hello! As always, you share awesome content! I'm getting an error when trying to save newly added data: TypeError: Cannot read property 'join' of undefined
I guess that since it doesn't have anything to compare against, it's giving me such error. Any light as to the root cause? Thank you very much!

Comment: @Antonio Santos Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. From your error message, I guessed that you are using the pattern 1. And the lengths of the arrays `data` and `pushedDbData` might be different. If my understanding is correct, I updated my answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your current situation, I apologize again. At that time, can you provide the sample values of `data` and `pushedDbData` and the sample output you expect? By this, I would like to modify my answer.

Comment: Hi! Thank you very much for your time. Now, although I've changed the month, when comparing, it says "no change has been made", considering pattern 1. Here's the sample: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xZVLD_f_H8noIicrIQQyHI6At0nORuQqhMPSYEoaw9U/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @Antonio Santos Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor understanding. Unfortunately, from your sample Spreadsheet, I cannot understand output you expect. And there are several functions in your script. Your question uses `saveFixedExpenses()`? If my understanding is correct, in your script in your question is used in a loop. And, `data` is the string value and `pushedDbData` is 3 dimensional array. From this situation, can  I ask you about the result you want? By this, I would like to think of the modification point. I deeply apologize for my poor English skill again.

Comment: Hello @Tanaike! I'm the one to apologize here, if I can't make my problem clear.
So, ```saveFixedExpenses``` is to get the data from sheet Fixed Expenses and compare it with what's in the FixedExpensesDB sheet. I've tried making the comparison using ```for (var x = 0; x < data.length; x++) {
      loop2:
      for (var j = 0; j < pushedDbData.length; j++) {
        if (data[x].join() == pushedDbData[j].join()) {
          duplicate = true;
          break loop1;
        }
      }
    }``` and it worked. I'd love to see this working the way you proposed, though. Thanks a million!

Comment: @Antonio Santos Thank you for replying and adding more information. From your additional information, I added one more modified script in my answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the result you expect, I apologize.

Comment: @Antonio Santos Thank you for quick reply and testing it again. I'm glad your issue was resolved. I could correctly understand about your question by your cooperation. Thank you, too.

Comment: Just re-used this one, which was right on point, after 2 days trying to figure out the solution. Thank you again!